# Door lock broken

Tags: doors, lock

How can I fix this problem with my door lock?

[image: Broken door lock]

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Stack Exchange. Some more description of what's wrong, and how it happened, would really help us.

Answer (score 3):

Buy a new deadbolt. You might be able to press those latch parts together for the very short term, but they won't last, and you run the risk of a stuck bolt/door.

Comment: So how do I fix it till get one

Comment: I don't think you can. Does the doorknob lock? Got a buddy that can buy you a deadbolt while you hang out at home?

Comment: Most doors that have a deadbolt also have a regular locking handle.  Until the fix is complete on the deadbolt you'll need to rely on the locking handle.  You can reinstall the deadbolt front and back without the broken part, to cover the hole.